# double parentecies doesn't work in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This worked

```
.container
        each item in items
            li= item.name
```

but not this

```
.container
        each item in items
            li {{item.name}}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

because each view engine has it own syntaxe, ie: `{{item.name}}` it work for `ejs` and not for `jade`.
by the way you can use this also in `jade`

```
.container
        each item in items
            li= #{item.name}
```